# uglifyjs drop_console / pure_funcs is not working in webpack

Tags: optimization, webpack, uglifyjs

I have the following configuration, but it still does not remove `console.log` statements:

```
new webpack.optimize.UglifyJsPlugin({
    compress: {
        warnings: false,
        pure_funcs: ['console.log'],
        drop_console: true,
        comments: false
    },
    pure_funcs: ['console.log'],
    drop_console: true,
    comments: false
})
```

What am I doing wrong?

Comment: Which version of webpack are you using?

Comment: version 1.14.0.

Answer (score 2):

It's possible that the messages you are getting are debugging messages in the console, rather than console.log. I had a similar issue where I thought using drop_console would suffice. I had to add drop_debugger as well, so given your example, this should remove all console output.

```
new webpack.optimize.UglifyJsPlugin({
  compress: {
    warnings: false,
    drop_console: true,
    drop_debugger: true
  },
  comments: false  
})
```

Answer (score 1):

It is not the reason of uglifyjs in my case. It is caused by babel-loader which will transform `console.log` to `(e = console).log`.

I do not know how to fix it now. Finally, I have to use a babel plugin named `babel-plugin-transform-remove-console` to remove console.

However I do want to use UglifyJsPlugin.

This is a hint for those who can find out a resolution.

Comment: It turns out that webpack is not very reliable here, and your solution with babel-plugin-transform-remove-console is much better.

Answer (score 0):

I had the same problem with `drop_console` not working in my react script setup (on Windows 10, React-script version 0.8.5).

Trying to reproduce this problem I created a brand new app, added `console.log` somewhere in App.js and `drop_console: true` in webpack.config.prod.js. However in this simple setup `drop_console` works and `console.log` is removed.

As it still didn't work in my real app I installed `strip-loader`:

```
npm install --save-dev strip-loader
```

then edited `webpack.config.prod.js` in `node_modules\react-scripts\config` (without ejecting from react):

```
var WebpackStrip = require('strip-loader'); // around line 20
...
// inserted in module/loaders between babel and style loaders, around line 168
  { 
    test: /\.js$/, 
    loader: WebpackStrip.loader('debug', 'console.log')
  },
```

Sure enough, all `console.log` statements were removed (`npm run build`). I then removed all my changes from the config and `console.log` were still being removed. I uninstalled `strip-loader` and the build still successfully removes `console.log` statements.

I cannot explain this behaviour, but at least it works (although somewhat magically).